# Moving default AppBundle under vendor

Tags: php, symfony

I have a new symfony project. By default it contains

```
-/AppBundle
-AppBundle.php
--/Controller
--/Default Controller
```

Since I am going to have more bundles I would like it to be under a VendorName called MyProject where I have my ApiBundle.

I have tried moving AppBundle manually, then changing namespaces in the files, yml files and AppKernel. But I still get an error

```
Expected to find class "AppBundle\AppBundle" in file "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/healthy-living/src/HealthyLiving/AppBundle/AppBundle.php" while importing services from resource "../../src/HealthyLiving/AppBundle/*", but it was not found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource.' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/healthy-living/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/FileLoader.php:133
```

Is there any console commands for doing this, if not what should be the procedures of moving it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There's no console command or procedure to do it because it's not what `vendor` folder was designed for. `vendor` folder is meant to store `3rd-party` code so keeping your own bundles, which you are developing, in `vendor` is not a good idea.

> Since I am going to have more bundles

There is no reason that you can't keep more than one bundle inside your `src` folder. In fact, when Symfony introduced Bundle system it was very common that `src` folder contained a lot of bundles.

(note that `vendor` folder is almost always added to `.gitignore` - that's because what I wrote before)

**EDIT after clarifying what the question is about:**
It looks like command to generate bundles has/had some issues with creating bundles without Vendor folder:

[Issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12227)

[Pull request](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/pull/312)

I don't know which version of Symfony are you using but either way creating bundle manually is always a good idea and it solves your problem too. (you can create it without vendor name)

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. When i was trying to add bundle without parent it asked for vendorname. 
The namespace must contain a vendor namespace (e.g. "VendorName\ApiBundle" instead of simply "ApiBundle").
If you've specified a vendor namespace, did you forget to surround it with quotes (init:bundle "Acme\BlogBundle")? - this is the vendor name i am refeering to

Comment: The AppBundle was there by default. When i generated ApiBundle in console it asked to be under VendorName which is e.g HealthyLiving, i could not make it in the same directory as AppBundle. So i would like to move AppBundle under the HealthyLiving, parent folder if you can call it that. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your API bundle to a repository (Github, Gitlab, Bitbucket, etc.) and then import it as an external dependency with Composer.

Comment: I've generated ApiBundle with console command and it was placed under VendorName - HealthyLiving, so I don't have provlems with that. It is the default AppBundle that has to be moved under Healthy living

Answer (score 0):

Since moving was too complicated because of the config files that has to be changed so I decided to do a workaround and remove it and then install via console under the same parent. Works like a charm. Althoug could be a method in cli for this.